# How to define a constructor for a typealias in Julia

Tags: julia

In Optim.jl we have a typealias `OptimizationTrace{T}` which is an alias for `Vector{OptimizationState{T}}` where `T` is of type `Optimizer`. I want to create a constructor `OptimizationTrace{T}(method::T) = OptimizationTrace{T}()`, but I am struggling to get it to work.

```
abstract Optimizer

immutable NelderMead <: Optimizer
end

immutable OptimizationState{T <: Optimizer}
    iteration::Int
    value::Float64
    g_norm::Float64
    metadata::Dict
end

typealias OptimizationTrace{T} Vector{OptimizationState{T}}

OptimizationTrace{NelderMead}() # works

# A different approach, define a convert-method.
OptimizationTrace{T}(method::T) = OptimizationTrace{T}() #     Doesn't work:
 ERROR: cannot define function OptimizationTrace; it already has a value

import Base.convert
convert{T<:Optimizer}(::Type{Array{OptimizationState{T},1}}, method::T) = OptimizationTrace{T}()
OptimizationTrace(NelderMead())
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Array{OptimizationState{T},1}}, ::NelderMead)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Array{OptimizationState{T},1}(...),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, the most straight forward way works in v0.5.

```
abstract Optimizer

immutable NelderMead <: Optimizer
end

immutable OptimizationState{T <: Optimizer}
                  iteration::Int
                  value::Float64
                  g_norm::Float64
                  metadata::Dict
              end

typealias OptimizationTrace{T} Vector{OptimizationState{T}}

OptimizationTrace{T<:Optimizer}(method::T) = Vector{OptimizationState{T}}()
OptimizationTrace(NelderMead())
```

Edit: and (credit due to Kristoffer Carlsson) on v0.4

```
call{T <: Optimizer}(::Type{OptimizationTrace}, method::T) = Vector{OptimizationState{T}}()
```